# Need help connecting Woocommerce store to external API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, e-commerce

so basically one of our clients has a Woocommerce packaging products store and he wants to sell his products on another store, the other store has an api and demanded us to create an api on the client's Woocommerce store in order for its products to show up on the other store.

• So it goes like this, the other store displays the dropshipper client's products by acquiring their stock and products through api

• Then after an order is placed on one of those said products, the payment is also handled on the other store and then the order information is communicated to the dropshipper client's store for them to handle the delivery and keep the other store updated with delivery tracking information through api also

Was wondering if anybody would be willing to help a junior intern dev out, how can i proceed with this task, already tried successfully pulling stock and products from the client's Woocommerce store using POSTMAN and the Woocommerce REST API but how do you RECIEVE information from an external API and handle it or store it in your Woocommerce store?

Thanks,

Comment: Either your requests to their API will contain some response data you can use, or, if you're waiting for them to send you information when something happens in their system, presumably they'll make a HTTP request to an endpoint in _your_ API, and you'll get the information that way.

Comment: the thing happening in their system is an order being placed and paid then they will send that order information to the woocommerce store, so how do i create an endpoint on my woocommerce side of things that recieves data from them? how do i even create an api on the woocommerce store?..

Comment: Oh ok, you're not even at that point. It's getting a bit broad for an SO question, and possibly a big deal for an internship project. Is there no-one else in your company supporting you with this?

Comment: P.S. https://simongondeck.com/how-to-use-woocommerce-api/ might be of use. (I don't know anything about woocommerce specifically, but typing "woocommerce create an api" led me to that and a couple of other links which looked like they'd be useful.)

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot for the reference, i checked the article and apparently it only shows you how to send Woocommerce REST requests to fetch/update/delete products, orders... etc using API clients like Insomnia and Postman, i already know how to do that, However unfortunately there's no word about how to handle responses from an external API and store those responses in your Woocommerce site

Comment: Ok. But the point is it shows you how to enable your API, and gives a summary of what endpoints are available in your woocommerce environment, if you enable them. This means you've got something which the other store could call (via HTTP) in order to send data to your store (or get data from you on-demand). How they actually initiate that call is up to them, but presumably they'd write some PHP code to do it. Remember, according to the scenario you described it's not you who's making the call to your API, it's the other store which needs to do that.

Comment: For full documentation of the available API endpoints, you should of course [consult the official documentation](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/)

Comment: @ADyson I guess maybe i have to handle this in custom php code instead of a client like Postman, this function called wp_remote_get() (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) and the Wordpress REST API documentation might also prove useful for saving responses from an external API

Comment: Sorry, why do you think _you_ need to handle anything? If the remote store wants to communicate with you, they should just choose the endpoint on your API that they want to call, and call it. That way, your store will then receive whatever they send to you.

Comment: And i assume that is done by giving them authorization/access to the Woocommerce site so that they can use the Woocommerce REST API endpoints like /wp-json/wc/v3/products ?

Comment: Its explained at https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/#section-2